# Why close 3 of my questions? How to improve them?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

##### [Is research being done on curing and reversing myopia, in adults ≥ 30 y.o.?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/32167)

1. Have there been  any advances, or more recent research, on *PERMANENTLY* CURING AND REVERSING myopia in adults at least 30 years old?
2. Even if the true answer to question 1 is "no", are any scientists actively researching this? If so, kindly link to their profile or website?

I ask NOT about  [LASEK, LASIK, RLE, LRI, PRELEX](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/9538) + or myopia reduction and prevention like

- [low-dose atropine eye drops](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/14297),
- [OrthoKeratologic contact lenses](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/20476),
- or  [boosting exposure to sunlight and the outdoors](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/15391).

---

> Questions here are required to show results of prior research.

I researched this question, and I couldn't find any advances.

---

##### [Is there evidence of a human's myopia permanently improving on its own, without surgery?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/32176)

##### Rule out

##### - anyone who has gotten [LASEK, LASIK, RLE, LRI, PRELEX](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/9538) surgery.

##### - ["second sight", namely spurious temporary improvements in distance vision](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/ask-ophthalmologist-q/distance-vision-improving-with-age).

Books like

- [William H. Bates MD, *The Bates Method for Better Eyesight without Glasses* (1981)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805002413)
- [David De Angelis, *The Secret of Perfect Vision: How You Can Prevent or Reverse Nearsightedness* (2008)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556436777)
- [Meir Schneider PhD, *Vision for Life, Revised Edition: Ten Steps to Natural Eyesight Improvement* (2016)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZNG3Q8Y)
- [Aileen Yi Fan, *Habits for Better Vision: 20 Scientifically Proven Ways to Improve Your Eyesight Naturally* (2019)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WNRSTS8)
- [Amelia Salvador MD, *Optimal Eyesight: How to Restore and Retain Great Vision* (2019)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08PPD1LKJ)

allege that you can improve your myopia.

#### But is there  peer-reviewed, scientific evidence or proof of ANY HUMAN whose myopia improved permanently after time?

---

This was wrongly closed for 2 reasons. First, [Jiminy Cricket.](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/15405/jiminy-cricket) [conflated it with the aforemention](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32176/is-there-evidence-of-a-humans-myopia-permanently-improving-on-its-own-without?noredirect=1#comment62413_32176). This question asks about PAST natural, unaided myopia improvement. The aforementioned question asks about ONGOING scientific research. Please peruse questions carefully.

Second, [Carey Gregory](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32176/is-there-evidence-of-a-humans-myopia-permanently-improving-on-its-own-without?noredirect=1#comment62422_32176) rebuked my research as "All the spammy links".  a Catch 22. If I  delete these links, then Carey Gregory shall chide me for no prior research. If I keep these links, then Carey Gregory shall upbraid them as spammy. What do I do?

---

##### [Does the OD teach you anything new, that you wouldn't learn in an MD?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/32175)

The below North American ophthalmologists were former optometrists. First they earned their OD  then MD.

##### 1. But does the other direction make sense? After earning your MD  does it ever make sense to study the OD?

##### 2. What, if anything, does the OD teach that isn't taught to MD students?

> [Dr. Wayne Anliker grew up in the Madison, KS area, earning his undergraduate degree at Kansas State University before earning his Doctor of Optometry degree from the University of Houston College of Optometry. He practiced optometry for three years before returning to the University of Kansas School of Medicine. After earning his medical degree at the University of Kansas School of Medicine, Dr. Anliker completed an internship at St. Vincent Hospital in Indianapolis, IN. He did his residency in ophthalmology at Indiana University.](https://www.reynoldsandanliker.com/doctors/wayne-anliker-m-d)

> [Dr. Patrick Ma is a clinical professor at the UBC Department of Ophthalmology since 1994 and current Head of the UBC Retina Division. Initially trained as an optometrist, Dr. Ma completed his residency in Ophthalmology in Ottawa and completed sub-specialty retinal fellowship in New Orleans.](https://ophthalmology.med.ubc.ca/patrick-ma)

> [Dr. Bryan Wong is a resident physician in the Department of Ophthalmology and Vision Sciences at the University of Toronto. He previously completed optometry training at the University of Waterloo, followed by medical training at the University of Toronto.](https://ondri.ca/wong-bryan)

> [Dr Vincent Lam is a dual fellowship trained Ophthalmologist who brings a novel skill set to the region. With surgical privileges at Oakville Trafalgar Memorial Hospital, Dr Lam specializes in cataract surgery, corneal surgery, laser refractive surgery, and uveitis. After completing his Ophthalmology residency, Dr Lam pursued a fellowship in Uveitis at the world-renowned Francis I. Proctor Foundation at the University of California, San Francisco. He subsequently completed a fellowship in Cornea, External Disease, and Refractive Surgery at Columbia University. **Dr Lam is also a former Optometrist. [emphasis mine]**](https://oteye.ca/about)

---

Same issue as above. I cited these CVs to showcase Ophthalmologists who were Optometrists. But Carey Gregory commented they are "spammy." If I didn't, then Carey Gregory may upbraid me for no prior research.

With respect, 
[Jiminy Cricket.](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/15405/jiminy-cricket) is wrong that these are ["commercial sites"](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32175/does-the-od-teach-you-anything-new-that-you-wouldnt-learn-in-an-md?noredirect=1#comment62412_32175). How is citing CVs commercial??? I am not touting or selling anything. I am not affiliated or sponsored by any of these websites or doctors.

Comment: This post is impossible to read. It seems you've just pasted a bunch of unrelated questions together.

Comment: I'm not going to go back and review a bunch of questions to explain why they were closed, so let's just take the most recent one. You asked why the AAO recommends putting drops in the corner of the eye, but if you read the link that _you_ provided, that's not what they recommend. Your question completely mischaracterizes their guidelines. So I closed your question as needing details, and the detail I have in mind is accurately quoting what they actually say. You can [edit] the question to correct the problem and it may be reopened.

Comment: The same would be true with your other questions if you had responded to the closure and fixed the problem in a timely manner, but you didn't so they've been automatically deleted by the system now.